# Android Studio Data Collection

Tags: android, android-studio, saving-data

I am designing an app for my job to collect data on dog training.  I need to be able to access the data on my computer to analyze it. I have completed the front end of the app and organized all of the information into a single string that I would like to save into a file for later analysis. I run the app and can not find the data anywhere on the tablet that runs the app. The code that saves the app is:

```
String output="Example, Data";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"TrainingData.txt");
try {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
    OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
    outputStream.write(output);
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there something wrong with the saving part of the code listed or is it correct and I'm just failing to find the file on the tablet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
File path = context.getFilesDir();
File file = new File(path, "the-file.txt");
```

and then:

```
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
try {
   stream.write(output".getBytes());
} finally {
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question but what is the context part?  I get an error if I put that in.

Comment: Where 're you running this code from? Fragment or Activity?